# Crypting and Securing Android data

Tags: java, android, eclipse, crypt

My app picks up the GPS location of the user every 5 minutes, saves it and then sends it to a server.
The problem I'm facing is I need the data stored on the android SD card to be Crypted so no one except me on the server can access it. Also I need to think of a way to make sure that no-one has edited the data except me.
For the last I've thought writing the MD5 checksum of the file each time I close it so when the app opens the file it checkes the MD5 to see if they match.
The problem with this is I think it'll waste resources and battery as I'm already checking for the GPS location every 5 minutes.
Any ideas would be appreciated as for crypting data I've been unable to find the most secure way
Thanks!!!

EDIT: I've already checked subjects on cryptography but everything seems so think that it's vulnerable to anyone with a little time, that's why I'm asking!

Comment: why you save the data on the SD card and not in sandbox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store your data using Sqlite with SqlCipher:
http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/

As you say, there is no way to completely prevent the data from being viewed/edited by a determined attacker, as you will have to expose your encryption key either in the program code or a save file somewhere on the system.

However no homegrown solution you or I could write would be any better, this is just the nature of the hardware/OS.

If you want the data safe from reading, I suggest you delete it after transmitting to the server.

Aside, if you're checking GPS every 5 minutes, there is hardly anything you could do that would be a noticeable battery drain compared to that.

Comment: So the attacker will always be able to edit my file with just a few minutes of his time hacking the encryptation key?

Comment: I would not say a "few minutes".  More like a "few days" for a determined and knowledgeable attacker, if you use proper encryption and your key algorithm is relatively complex.  For many applications this is an unacceptable security risk, you'll have to decide if it is OK for yours.